# When returning a Laravel model, how do I restrict columns while also using with()?

Tags: php, laravel

I have a model User defined as below:

```
<?php
class User extends Eloquent {

public function roles() {
  return $this->belongsToMany('Role');
}
```

How do I write a query which will fetch only specific fields from `User`, along with all fields from each `Role`?¨ I do not want to use the `hidden` property on the `User` model, because in different cases I want different subsets of the fields.

This works, but of course returns all fields from `User`:

```
$user = User::with('roles')->findOrFail($id);
```

This correctly limits the fields of `User` but returns nothing for the `roles` - just an empty array

```
$user = User::with('roles')->select(['name','email'])->findOrFail($id);
```

Any attempt to reference the `roles` field inside the select gives an error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to do this way in eager loading.

```
$user = User::with(array('roles' => function($q)
    {
        $q->select('field1');

    }))->select(['name','email'])->findOrFail($id);
```

Comment: Thanks, accepting this answer because the mention of eager loading helped me find more in the Laravel docs.

Answer (score 4):

Try this code:

```
$with = array('roles' => array('id', 'name'));
$user = User::with($with);
```

See if that help.